# Identify user's location and include it in the response sent to the my app on MS Teams

Tags: gps, microsoft-teams, userlocation

To find the location of the user, I wrote the below code:

> geoLocation.getCurrentLocation()
> .then((res) => {
> console.log({ "Execute getCurrentLocation": res });
> })
> .catch((error) => {
> console.log({ "error while Execute getCurrentLocation ": error });
> });

but I get the following error `'one or more provided argument is invalid' when the api gets called. This error is also mentioned on the official site of Microsoft (Error code - 4000).`
can you help me to resolving this error

Answer (score 0):

The TeamsJS library provides getLocation API that you can use to fetch the current location of the user.

```
microsoftTeams.initialize();
microsoftTeams.location.getLocation((err, location) => {
    if (err) {
        console.error('Error getting location: ' + err);
    } else {
        console.log('Location: ' + JSON.stringify(location));
    }
});
```

The location is returned in the callback function as a Location object, which contains the latitude and longitude of the user's location.

Also, you need to update your app's manifest file to include the devicePermissions field with the geolocation permission.

```
{
    "devicePermissions": ["geolocation"]
}
```

Sample Ref: https://github.com/OfficeDev/Microsoft-Teams-Samples/tree/main/samples/app-checkin-location

Comment: Please refer: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/concepts/device-capabilities/native-device-permissions?tabs=mobile%2Cteamsjs-v2%2Cmobile1#manage-permissions

Comment: I get the following error 'one or more provided argument is invalid' when the api gets called. This error is also mentioned on the official site of Microsoft (Error code - 4000).

Comment: The error code 4000, INVALID_ARGUMENTS, indicates that the `getLocation` API is invoked with wrong or insufficient mandatory arguments. This error is generated when the API is called with incorrect or missing required parameters. Check the parameters you are passing to the `getLocation` API. Ensure that all required parameters are provided and they are in the correct format and also validate the data types of the arguments.

Comment: But getLocation  is deprecated from msTeams They provided another option is getCurrentLocation this is what we are using
I wrote the below code:
geoLocation.getCurrentLocation() .then((res) => {
console.log({ "Execute getCurrentLocation": res }); }) .catch((error) => { console.log({ "error while Execute getCurrentLocation ": error }); });

Comment: From above mentioned code it seems like the method is called without any arguments as it doesn't require any. If you're seeing error 4000 with this API, it might be due to an issue with the Teams client or platform. Make sure you're using the latest version of the Teams client and the Teams JavaScript SDK.